# Switch Case change when updated Flutter SDK to Null Safety

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-dependencies

So I have updated the Flutter SDK and my swtich case functions work the same but now the `break;` after each case in considered as dead code. I wonder why is that? I tried removing the `return` statement but then the UI won't switch/change when the right parameter is achieved. The code:

Old Switch case statement before the update:

```
panelButtonsChange() {
    switch (Provider.of<Store>(context).panelButtons) {
      case 1:
        return SomeClassButton(
        onPressed: () {
          store.setNumber(2);
        },
        buttonTitle: "Action 1",
        );
        break;
      case 2:
        return SomeClassButton(
        onPressed: () {
          store.setNumber(3);
        },
        buttonTitle: "Action 2",
        );
     
        break;
      case 3:
        return SomeClassButton(
        onPressed: () {
          store.setNumber(4);
        },
        buttonTitle: "Action 3");
        break;
  
    }
    return SomeClassButton(
        onPressed: () {
          store.setNumber(1);
        },
        buttonTitle: "Default action",
      );
  }
```

Same Switch case statement but after the update to null safety (SDK `>=2.12.0`):

```
panelButtonsChange() {
    switch (Provider.of<Store>(context).panelButtons) {
      case 1:
        return SomeClassButton(
        onPressed: () {
          store.setNumber(2);
        },
        buttonTitle: "Action 1",
        );
        break; // THIS IS NOW DEAD CODE
      case 2:
        return SomeClassButton(
        onPressed: () {
          store.setNumber(3);
        },
        buttonTitle: "Action 2",
        );
     
        break; // THIS IS NOW DEAD CODE
      case 3:
        return SomeClassButton(
        onPressed: () {
          store.setNumber(4);
        },
        buttonTitle: "Action 3");
        break; // THIS IS NOW DEAD CODE
  
    }
    return SomeClassButton(
        onPressed: () {
          store.setNumber(1);
        },
        buttonTitle: "Default action",
      );
  }
```

If I remove the `return` statement in the new updated switch case, then the problem is that the buttons won't change in the UI because it is missing the `return` statement. Is `break;` now deprecated or am I missing something here? The weird part is that it still works normally like it use to, but I'm not sure if it was meant to work that way and should I remove the dead code or not.. Thanks in advance for your help.

UPDATE: Case where I don't use the `return` but execute an action (in this case call an API):

```
switch (buttonNumber) {
      case 0:
        SomeActionClass(context).fetchAPI();
        break;
      case 1:
        SomeActionClass(context).fetchOtherAPI();
        break;
      case 2:
        SomeActionClass(context).fetchYetAnotherAPI();
        break;
    }
```

Here I have no return statement but the API calls are executed based on the case that is met.

Comment: What is confusing you about the "UPDATE:" code?

Comment: @jamesdlin Yeah, I'm just having a bad day and realizing my stupidity at this point, I'm trying to reinvent the wheel... I apologize for wasting your time. All is clear now, thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says so because each `break` after the `return` will never be actually executed. I mean, any code after a `return` will never get executed, and `break` is no exception. You can simply remove the breaks, and your code won't even notice. The `switch` will behave as before, because when it will find a relevant `case`, the function will `return` and the other cases won't be evaluated.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the logic for the `return` part, but what's confusing is that if I remove the return, why isn't my widget or widgets changing based upon the switch case that is met, or like you said, relevant? Is it because I am returning a widget? Because in some switch cases, I don't `return` anything but I call a function. I will update the question with that case also.

Comment: @GrandMagus Nobody's telling you to remove the `return` statements.  You should remove the redundant `break` statements.  Removing the `return` statements will break your code because that will obviously make it no longer return the same value to its caller, changing its behavior.